# Проблема с List в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, list

Я писал нейронную сеть для игры и мне началась выдаваться ошибка о выходе за пределы листа как я понял:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index
>           System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
>   (at :0)
>
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at :0)
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at :0)
>
> Brains.WeightsInit () (at Assets/Scripts/Brains.cs:77)
>
> Brains.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Brains.cs:29)`

---

Вот часть того кода, на который он ругается:

```
`        float randomNumb = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
            {
                wEH.Add(new List<float>());
                for(int j = 0; j < hidden.Length; i++)
                {
                    randomNumb = Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f);
                    wEH[i].Add(randomNumb);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < hidden.Length; i++)
            {
                wHO.Add(new List<float>());
                for (int j = 0; j < outputs.Length; i++)
                {
                    wHO[i].Add(Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f));
                }
            }`

    Инициализация листа: 
`    List<List<float>> wEH = new List<List<float>>();
        List<List<float>> wHO = new List<List<float>>();`
```

Comment: Он не "ругается на часть кода". Он ругается на конкретную строчку. Какая строчка в приведенном коде  `Assets/Scripts/Brains.cs:77`?

Comment: 77 строчка -     wEH[i].Add(randomNumb);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j < hidden.Length; j++) // было i++
...
for (int j = 0; j < outputs.Length; j++)  // было i++
```